# Optimize map reduce operations in apache nutch

Tags: hadoop, nutch

In Nutch 1.8:

At the start of the crawl, the map-reduce task detailed below seem to run much faster. However, after crawling only 40,000 pages, the map-reduce task seems to take much longer. Looking at logs below, it takes a second to accomplish 1% of the map-reduce task. Any ideas on what is making the map-reduce task take so long to finish? I am just dumping the crawl results via `-dir` parameter in a directory, with no added configuration in hadoop nor am I using additional storage libraries. Thanks.

**Additional question:**

Upon further investigation of the problem, still can't understand what this map-reduce task does. Why does Nutch perform this?

```
2015-11-19 10:07:16,707 INFO  regex.RegexURLNormalizer (RegexURLNormalizer.java:regexNormalize(174)) - can't find rules for scope 'crawldb', using default
2015-11-19 10:07:17,172 INFO  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1393)) -  map 57% reduce 0%
2015-11-19 10:07:22,664 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(466)) - file:/C:/Users/user/workspace/trunk/crawl/crawldb/current/part-00000/data:100663296+33554432
2015-11-19 10:07:23,172 INFO  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1393)) -  map 59% reduce 0%
2015-11-19 10:07:25,664 INFO  mapred.LocalJobRunner (LocalJobRunner.java:statusUpdate(466)) - file:/C:/Users/user/workspace/trunk/crawl/crawldb/current/part-00000/data:100663296+33554432
2015-11-19 10:07:26,172 INFO  mapred.JobClient (JobClient.java:monitorAndPrintJob(1393)) -  map 60% reduce 0%
```

Comment: @ravindra run configurations are `urls -dir crawl -depth 500 -topN 150` with 40,000 pages already crawled.